# If a legatee receives a legacy, what is the legacy giver called? Maybe legateer?

Tags: nouns, infinitives, synonyms, definition

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who leaves a legacy. It would be nice to call someone or a group of people that word. Similar to how being a maverick is someone who's different from the rest. I thought legateer would work, but this word doesn't exist.

Comment: Bequeather crops up (though not much) as a derived noun of bequeath.

Comment: Note that a testator is someone who writes a will, a legator is someone who leaves a legacy, so though they may be the same person, they are used in reference to different acts and therefore are not contextual equivalents.

Answer (score 14):

The *legal* term here is...

> [**testator**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/testator) *- a person who dies leaving a will or testament in force*

...but you'd rarely hear that in normal conversational contexts. Ordinary people don't have a word for "person who died leaving a will" - presumably because there's little need for it outside of legal contexts.

---

BUT - if we move slightly away from the specific context of "dead person's last will and testament", there will often be contexts where the appropriate word is...

> [**benefactor**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benefactor)
> *someone or something that provides help or an advantage : one that confers a benefit*
> especially : *a person who makes a **gift or bequest***

Answer (score 6):

Legator

In [UK English](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/legator)

Seems to be [valid in US](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/legator) too.

I don't recall ever having used either legatee or legator. I would use beneficiary and benefactor.

Comment: The full OED entry for **legator**, definition *A person who gives something by will; a **testator,*** has "frequency indicator" value 2 (out of a maximum 8). But their entry for ***testator*** has frequency **5**. Until I just checked [the relevant NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=legator%2Ctestator%2Cbenefactor&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clegator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctestator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbenefactor%3B%2Cc0) I'd have thought ***benefactor*** was far more common, but apparently it's about on a par with ***testator***.

Comment: To emphasise @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica's point: the frequency bands are logarithmic - each is roughly 10 times more frequent than the previous. So a frequency **5** word is about 1,000 times more common than a frequency  **2** one.

Comment: @TripeHound: I didn't know that useful snippet. Ty for the info! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica See the freely-accessible [Key to frequency](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-frequency/) for all the gory details!

Answer (score 1):

Also, you may want to look at [the differences between legatee, devisee and beneficiary](https://nyestateslawyer.com/2018/11/17/legatee-devisee-distributee-and-beneficiary-ny/)

> Beneficiary– a person entitled to any part or all of an estate.
> Legatee– a person designated by a will to receive a transfer of
> personal property. Devisee– a person designated by a will to receive a
> transfer of real property.